# SSH Authentication with Fido2 / Yubico Security Key

Tags: ssh, u2f

I was wondering if it is possible to use FIDO2 to authenticate against an ssh server. There are many tutorials explaining how to use GPG and the newer Yubikeys for ssh auth, but i do not find any information on if it is possible or how it is possbile to use FIDO2 or U2F (especially Yubico Security Key NFC) to authenticate against an ssh server.

Answer (score 3):

Good news!  [OpenSSH 8.2](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-8.2) has added support for FIDO/U2F.  No more need for a patch.

> ### FIDO/U2F Support
>
> This release adds support for FIDO/U2F hardware authenticators to
>   OpenSSH. U2F/FIDO are open standards for inexpensive two-factor
>   authentication hardware that are widely used for website
>   authentication.  In OpenSSH FIDO devices are supported by new public
>   key types `ecdsa-sk` and `ed25519-sk`, along with corresponding
>   certificate types.
>
> `ssh-keygen`(1) may be used to generate a FIDO token-backed key, after
>   which they may be used much like any other key type supported by
>   OpenSSH, so long as the hardware token is attached when the keys are
>   used. FIDO tokens also generally require the user explicitly authorise
>   operations by touching or tapping them.
>
> Generating a FIDO key requires the token be attached, and will usually
>   require the user tap the token to confirm the operation:
>
> ```
>   $ ssh-keygen -t ecdsa-sk -f ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
>   Generating public/private ecdsa-sk key pair.
>   You may need to touch your security key to authorize key generation.
>   Enter file in which to save the key (/home/djm/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk): 
>   Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): 
>   Enter same passphrase again: 
>   Your identification has been saved in /home/djm/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
>   Your public key has been saved in /home/djm/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk.pub
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You can use pams provided by yubico.

`libpam-yubico` for otp authentication can be used. [ref](https://developers.yubico.com/yubico-pam/)

`libpam-u2f` for u2f (can't be used with ssh since it uses libusb which reads only local ports.)

BTW: You dont need PPA it is already in repo (at least Debian).

Answer (score -1):

This is possible by [patching the OpenSSH server and client](https://github.com/Yubico/pam-u2f/issues/12#issuecomment-148917351).

Since this patch is not integrated in the official OpenSSH code and looks pretty hacky, it could contain bugs and vulnerabilities.

Comment: could provide something about the "how" ?